# Apache Rewrite_Module is not working in Xampp, windows 10

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I am trying to catch all url request to www.domain.com/Index with Rewrite_module.

.htaccess code is like this..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php code is like this.

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
   echo $url;
}
```

I am getting value of $_GET['url'] when I am trying URL like www.domain.com/index.php?url=Index

but when I trying www.domain.com/Index. it gives me a blank page without any error.

I need to collect $_GET['url'] value to use url like domain/Food/Snacks/Samoosa

using: Xampp, windows 10, Netbeans.

Comment: Make sure that mod_rewrite is on.

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse it is not found else condition in your code so may be beacuse of that you are getting beacuse in your code nothing to show in web page use below code it may help you.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
       echo $url;
    }
    else{
    echo "Nothing found";
    }
```

?>

Try to disable MultiViews in htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: I already tried this. i used this function also $url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url');

Comment: Try to disable MultiViews in htaccess:

Options -MultiViews

Comment: how can i disable it?.

Comment: just put below code in .htaccess file 
Options -MultiViews

Comment: Same results. no change in results. for more clarification, actually I am getting all URL requests in my index.php and it is visible to. the thing is I am not able to collect the values through $_GET['url'], which follow after the domain. (EG: "Homepage" from www.domain.com/Homepage.

Comment: then you have to use $_SERVER['REQUSET_URI'] to get url value